# Vim: Auto Formatting Long Single Lines

Tags: vim, formatting, code-formatting

I have a JavaScript code written as a one long line and I want to re-format that so that each statement is written in one line. Is that possible using Vim? I tried the gqq and == commands and they didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will probably be easier to reformat using regexp first :

`:%s/;/;\r/gc`
`:%s/}/}\r/gc`
`:%s/{/{\r/gc`
etc

to insert line return after ; or { }.

(if you are confident enough or the file is to long, do not use `c` it will ask for a confirmation for each match)

Once your file is split on different lines, you can use `gg=G` to get the correct indentation.

As far as I know it is not possible to split a line on multiple lines with either gq or =

Comment: `:%s/\([;}{]\)/\1\r/gc` is more convient.

Answer (score 3):

There is a vim plugin that enables formatting on your code from within vim (with one button press). It's called vim-autoformat and you can dowload it here:

https://github.com/vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat

It integrates external code-formatting programs into vim.
For example, if you want to format javascript code, you only need to install the program js-beautifier (it's explained in the repo), and everything works, without having to configure stuff.

Answer (score 0):

would be nice to put these actions into a function, making
the job simpler.

```
function! FormatJavaScript()   
    :%s/;/;\r/gc
    :%s/}/}\r/gc
    :%s/{/{\r/gc
endfun
map <F2> <esc>:call FormatJavaScript()<cr>
```

a further improvement in function would be to put a gap, so that the function acts on it, instead of acting on the entire file, which does not remember at the moment. I'll take a look at "help command", could someone help with this?